# React Native upload image to server on iOS

Tags: react-native, file-upload, react-native-ios

I use react-native-image-picker to get image from IOS device (emulator), this my code:

```
try {
      ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(
        {
          quality: 0.7,
          storageOptions:{
            skipBackup:true,
            cameraRoll:true,
            waitUntilSaved:true
          }
        },
        (response) => {
          console.log(response);
          if (response.didCancel || response.error === "Camera not available on simulator") return;
          camera(response);
        }
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
```

and after that, I have object with uri, origURL, data and other params
I try to upload this image to server with this code:

```
const postFormData = (url, formData, token) => {
  return fetch(URL_API + url, {
    body: formData,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
})
    .then(response => {console.log(response); return response.json()})
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        alert("Upload failed!");
    });
}
```

my formData:

```
photo = {
              uri: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? image.origURL.replace("file://", "") : image.uri,
              type: image.type,
              name: image.fileName,
              data: image.data,
          };
var form = new FormData();
form.append("image",photo);
```

I try origUrl, uri, try this:`'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + image.data`  instead uri, try with `replace("file://", "")`, without `replace("file://", "")` it all don't work.
if I try upload with uri I have this error: [image]

if I try upload with origURL I have this error: [image]

if I try upload with `'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + image.data`  instead uri I have some error in console.

How I can upload image? Maybe this problem only on iOS simulator? Help, please!))

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I can't upload image with image.origURL and image.uri, but when I insert instead uri `data:image/jpeg;base64,' + image.data`, I can't upload image because of file size, it was too big, now I use quality 0.1 in imagePicker option, and all work fine (sorry for my English)))